# (rails_admin 3) Unsupported field datatype: timestamptz

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-admin

I'm getting this error when rails_admin try to access a model mapped to a PostgreSQL table with a field type "`timestamp with time zone`", example: http://localhost:3000/client

**Error Message:**

I get the following error in the console:

```
Unsupported field datatype: timestamptz
```

**Error Backtrace:**

```
rails_admin (3.1.2) lib/rails_admin/config/fields/types.rb:14:in `block in load'
rails_admin (3.1.2) lib/rails_admin/config/fields/types.rb:14:in `fetch'
rails_admin (3.1.2) lib/rails_admin/config/fields/types.rb:14:in `load'
rails_admin (3.1.2) lib/rails_admin/config/fields.rb:17:in `block in <module:Fields>'
rails_admin (3.1.2) lib/rails_admin/config/fields.rb:57:in `block (2 levels) in factory'
rails_admin (3.1.2) lib/rails_admin/config/fields.rb:57:in `each'
rails_admin (3.1.2) lib/rails_admin/config/fields.rb:57:in `detect'
rails_admin (3.1.2) lib/rails_admin/config/fields.rb:57:in `block in factory'
rails_admin (3.1.2) lib/rails_admin/config/fields.rb:52:in `each'
rails_admin (3.1.2) lib/rails_admin/config/fields.rb:52:in `factory'
rails_admin (3.1.2) lib/rails_admin/config/has_fields.rb:135:in `_fields'
rails_admin (3.1.2) lib/rails_admin/config/has_fields.rb:138:in `_fields'
rails_admin (3.1.2) lib/rails_admin/config/has_fields.rb:109:in `all_fields'
rails_admin (3.1.2) lib/rails_admin/config/has_fields.rb:84:in `fields'
rails_admin (3.1.2) app/controllers/rails_admin/main_controller.rb:127:in `get_collection'
```

**Stack:**

- Rails 7.0.4.3
- Ruby 3.1.3
- gem rails_admin 3.1.2
- gem pg 1.4.6
- Postgres server 12.9

**Context:**

If i change the type of the field to "timestamp without time zone", it works fine, but i need the time zone.

I know this was supported because it worked with rails_admin 2 and rails 5.

Inspecting the error in the gem i can see there are not a :timestamptz key in the  types registry, but :timestamp only.

`rails_admin (3.1.2) lib/rails_admin/config/fields/types.rb:14`

```
>> @@registry.keys
=> [:text, :action_text, :string, :enum, :active_record_enum, :file_upload, :active_storage, :belongs_to_association, :boolean, :bson_object_id, :composite_keys_belongs_to_association, :datetime, :date, :numeric, :decimal, :dragonfly, :paperclip, :carrierwave, :multiple_file_upload, :multiple_active_storage, :multiple_carrierwave, :float, :has_many_association, :has_and_belongs_to_many_association, :has_one_association, :integer, :password, :polymorphic_association, :hidden, :serialized, :shrine, :time, :timestamp, :color, :simple_mde, :ck_editor, :code_mirror, :wysihtml5, :froala, :json, :jsonb, :inet, :uuid, :citext]
```

**PostgresSQL table definition:**

```
CREATE TABLE public.clients (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
    updated_at timestamp with time zone,
    slug character varying(100) NOT NULL
);
```

**Model definition:**

`app/models/client.rb`

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find a monkey patch solution for this issue [here](https://github.com/railsadminteam/rails_admin/issues/3615).

The solution adds a missing `timestamptz.rb` file in `lib/rails_admin/config/fields/types/`

See the issue link for detailed explanation.